# Получить из листа сумму параметров объектов в один запрос

Tags: c#

Имеется `list` объектов `Test`, у которого, к примеру, есть поля `Name`, `Number1`, `Number2` ... `Number20`. Как с помощью LINQ в один проход по циклу получить результирующий объект, имеющий, к примеру, сумму каждого поля (т.е. в результирующем объекте в `Number1` будет записана сумма всех `Number1`, в `Number2` сумма всех `Number2` и т.д.).

Так как имеется около 20 полей, то получается 20 проходов по циклу (если делать стандартной функцией Sum), а я хочу сделать это за 1 проход используя функцию `Sum`. Аналогично нужно еще сделать для `Max`, `Min` и `Average`

Comment: Позвольте узнать зачем?

Comment: Извините, такие подробности я не могу раскрыть

Comment: я ж не прошу рассказать что вы делаете. Я хочу понять почему именно LINQ, когда в одном цикле можно посчитать сразу все случаи и это будет за 1 проход и куда понятнее декларативного выражения LINQ.

Comment: Да можно через цикл, но есть один момент.

Если для суммы этот код будет кое как приемлем,  то при нахождении максимального и минимального значения мне придется на каждом поле делать проверку.

Comment: То же самое вам придется делать и в LINQ, потому что ваша задача решается только через Aggregate...с теми же действиями внутри. Разница всего лишь в выражении "функциональное" против "императивного"

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
var res = list.Aggregate(new Test(), (one, two) =>
            new Test
            {
                Number1 = one.Number1 + two.Number1,
                Number2 = one.Number2 + two.Number2
                //и так далее...
            });
```

Мне кажется, Вам стоит пересмотреть и упростить приложение.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но я такой подход рассматривал, его можно заменить на обычный цикл foreach(все равно он быстрее чем LINQ). При этом если для Sum можно аккуратненько просто сложить и код не будет громоздким, то при нахождении максимального и минимально придется проверять на условие для каждого поля.

Comment: @Snuppi не нужно проверять условие для каждого поля, проще написать `Number1 = Math.Max(one.Number1, two.Number2)`

Comment: Точно, как то я не подумал про это:D Спасибо огромное)))